# Собачьи команды

Tags: этимология

Среди команд, отдаваемых собакам, есть вполне понятные вроде "сидеть" или "лежать", а есть и такие как "фас", "апорт", "ату" и прочее. Что это: случайное сочетание звуков или эти слова что-то означают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти слова используются в русском языке как междометия. Они часто иноязычного происхождения, так, например, ФАС - от немецкого fassen (взять, тронуть), АПОРТ - французское слово "apporte" со значением "принеси".

ату
ату́ межд., клич к охотничьим собакам, откуда ату́кать, ату́кнуть "травить, гнать" (Гоголь). По Преобр. (1,10) звукоподражательное. Скорее, из франц. à tout.

Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.